# Repeater in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I have created three datasets for my report. Also, I have taken three tables inside the data region to show the data.

I have one parameter that that is customer ID to filter the data.

Now my question is that I want to repeat all the three table data customer wise in a separate page.

For example:

Customer id is 1,2,3,4,5,6

Data should be displayed as

```
Customer Id 1
Table1 
Table2
Table3

Customer Id 2
Table 1
Table 2
Table 3

Customer Id 3
Table 1
Table 2
Table 3
```

and so on

Comment: Create 1 dataset. Without looking at dataset one way to accomplish is doing UNION ALL. Can you show what kind of data is in each table and why you need 3 datasets.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Group on the customer ID  and then list all three table within that group.

Force a new page on the Group change (begin or after)

This will give you the report that you are looking for.

Comment: Hi Hiten,
My query is little bit different.I have 3 dataset and 3 tablix region means in the data region and for all the three dataset has Customer Id Column.

Now my requirement is i want to show the data for customer id 1 for all the three tablix data region then for customer 2 then customer 3 and so on.

In Cognos Reporting Toll there is one repeater option,is there any repeater type option in ssrs or how can i fullfill this requirement.

Comment: you can put filter on the 3 tablix wirh customer ID.