# SSRS Real time scenarios

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssis, ssas

I am running in to a problem in SSRS 2.0 where I have a report that generates data based on 2 perameters, Manager and Month. For each month there are around 20-25 managers.

The final report contains 3 different tables per manager that are not connected.

What I would like to do is make the report display the 3 tables for each manager on a given month so it would look something like this:

Manager A:

Table 1

Table 2

Table 3

Manager B:

Table 1

Table 2

Table 3

And so on...

My only thought is to copy and paste the 3 tables 20+ times and make each set of tables refer to a different manager.

I tried but I Didn't..! post the answer anyone..!

Comment: I tried but I Didn't too!

Comment: Looks duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19209632/repeater-in-ssrs

Comment: 3 Tablix, 3 datasets, pass the month and manager parameters and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

Create one Master report which is having 25 subreports. In subreport place the 3 tables and refer them. You can pass the harcoded manager parameter to each subreport.